# Xpath same type child node concatanation with line break in xpath 1.0

Tags: xml, function, xpath, append, line-breaks

I have an XML in the following format

```
<books>
      <book>ABC</book>
      <book>CDE</book>
      <book>FGH</book>
</books>
```

Is it possible for me to get the values inside `<book>` tag concatenated into a single field with a line break between each value using an XPath function? I mean the return field is something like
this as single field.

```
ABC
CDE
FGH
```

Can I achieve this using an XPath function because the 3 tags have same name? I can split and get the individual elements separately using `{split(xpath('//books'),' ',0)}` (returns ABC)

I checked the split function it seems to be for one tag but here are 3 tags.

Comment: Do you mean `string-join(//book, ' ')`?

Comment: there should be a line break between the values when joining

Comment: Oh... right. `string-join(//book, codepoints-to-string(10))`

Comment: thanks the problem is this is version XPATH 1.0 . Thats the issue. Is there a work around for string-join(//book, codepoints-to-string(10)) in xpath 1.0?

Comment: In XPath 1.0 `concat` is your only option string-join(//book, codepoints-to-string(10))

Comment: yes thanks how can I use concat() to  achieve it?